# React native okhttp3 production crash

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, okhttp, production

Hello i recently made an ios update to my already working react native project which i am able to also run the android version but for some reason after doing ios updates and so on.. i made a ".aab" for the android after checking through in development where everything was alright but when i installed the production ".aab" on an android i get the below warning after blootsplash screen is gone which i believe it crashes when it wants to make a request to the server.

i did whatever i could to see the differences between before i started the ios updates and after and i didnt change anything regarding okhttp3 or anything related, so can anyone direct me or help me understand what below error means and why happening in production mode ?

[image]